# Opensubtitles api python data is not a dictionary

Tags: python, api

the documentation:
https://trac.opensubtitles.org/projects/opensubtitles/wiki/XMLRPC

```
from xmlrpc.client import ServerProxy

url = 'http://api.opensubtitles.org/xml-rpc'
server = ServerProxy(url)
token = server.LogIn('username', 'Password', 'eng', 'TemporaryUserAgent')['token']
data = server.SearchSubtitles(token, [{'sublanguageid': 'english', 'query': 'Movie Name'}])
```

I print data and it has IDSubtitleFile in it. but then I try

```
id_subtitle_file = data.get('IDSubtitleFile')
```

and it prints None

I have seen it done this way too

```
id1= data.get('data')
subtitle_id = id1.get('IDSubtitleFile'))
```

but this throws  'list' object has no attribute 'get'

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you reformat your question properly? No idea what is `ServerProxy`, same as required and returned types. It is just comment with some random information inside

Comment: documentation added, and imports added. this is literally my entire code, let me know what else you need

Answer (score 0):

Please check the API documentation: [here](https://trac.opensubtitles.org/projects/opensubtitles/wiki/XMLRPC)

The search request response structure:

```
 {
   status: ...
   data: [    # <-- array
      ...records...
   ]
  }
```

Code sample below:

```
from xmlrpc.client import ServerProxy


server = ServerProxy("http://api.opensubtitles.org/xml-rpc")
token = server.LogIn('username', 'pass', 'eng', 'TemporaryUserAgent')['token']
response = server.SearchSubtitles(token, 
     [{'sublanguageid': 'english', 'query': 'Movie Name'}]
   )


for record in response["data"]:
    print(record["IDSubtitleFile"])
```

Comment: This is the answer, I am new to apis so I appreciate the help